# Opening and then breaking links to a Word document from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an excel spreadsheet that is linked to multiple Word documents (.docx), which act as templates.

I have written a macro that opens the required word template from excel (the template chosen is dependent on the value of cell M17). The links in the word template update automatically as word opens. I am then trying to break the links of the document that I opened. This is what I have so far:

```
Function FnOpeneWordDoc()

   Dim objWord

   Dim objDoc

   Dim path As String

   path = Range("M17")

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("*file_path*" & path & ".docx")

   objWord.Visible = True

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))

   objDoc.Fields.Unlink

End Function
```

I suspect that it isn't working because the macro is trying to break the links before the document has fully loaded (and therefore the existing links haven't had a chance to update?), which is why I added the wait. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the solution.

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://wordribbon.tips.net/T002357_Breaking_Links_in_Lots_of_Documents.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is not the solution I am after; I am not trying to break links to multiple documents at once. Instead, I am trying to break the links to a specific word document (which could be one of around 10 templates) from excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code would have been fine, but I didn't realise that the code had to be different if the text was in textboxes.

I struggled to break the links within textboxes, and kept getting run-time error 438. However, I found a workaround:

I wrote a sub in the word documents:

```
Sub Unlink

Selection.Fields.Unlink

End Sub
```

I then called this macro from my excel document:

```
Sub FnOpeneWordDoc()

   Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("filename")

   objWord.Visible = True

   For i = 1 To objDoc.Shapes.Count

    objDoc.Shapes(i).Select

    objDoc.Application.Run ("unlink")

   Next

End Sub
```